# Detecting generic type in TypeScript

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm writing a simple method which accepts a string as an argument to look up as a key from an object. This method has a generic type, which will be used to typecast the returned object. However, this isn't quite working as expected. Is it actually possible to typecast values, and if so, how do I do this?

```
class Application
{
    private values : {[s : string] : string} = {
        "foo" : "bar",
        "test" : "1234"
    }

    public getValue<T>(key : string) : T
    {
        if (this.values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            switch (typeof T) {                  // Doesn't work
                case "string":
                    return this.values[key].toString();
                case "number":
                    return parseInt(this.values[key]);
                default:
                    throw new Error("Type of T is not a valid return type!");
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error("Key '" + key + "' does not exist!");
        }
    }
}

var app : Application = new Application();
app.getValue<number>("test"); // Should return 1234
app.getValue<string>("test"); // Should return '1234'
```

Comment: how about checking typeof key, not typeof T?

Comment: @uksz the variable `key` will always be a string, as I'm accessing values from an object, I'm pretty much just trying to get my code to typecast my value to the correct format

Comment: That's not really what generics are meant for: your list is anything but generic. Right now, the caller needs to know how it wants to interpret the resulting value, so why not just make that an explicit parameter? `getValue(key: string, type: string) { switch (type) { // type switching } }`. Note that even though `T` must be a type, you're not actually *using* that type to cast the value: you're just taking different actions depending on what the caller requested. So the explicit, string-based type is pretty much equivalent, and has the added benefit of working.

Comment: @dlev I'll try doing that, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing `key` and `T` in your method. I would write it like that:

```
public getValue<T>(key : string) : T
{
    if (this.values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        switch (typeof key) {                  // Doesn't work
            case "string":
                return this.values[key].toString();
            case "number":
                return parseInt(this.values[key]);
            default:
                throw new Error("Type of T is not a valid return type!");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error("Key '" + key + "' does not exist!");
    }
}
```

You will get better understanding of how TypeScript works by using [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). You can see how your code compiles:

```
var Application = (function () {
function Application() {
    this.values = {
        "foo": "bar",
        "test": "1234"
    };
}
Application.prototype.getValue = function (key) {
    if (this.values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        switch (typeof T) {
            case "string":
                return this.values[key].toString();
            case "number":
                return parseInt(this.values[key]);
            default:
                throw new Error("Type of T is not a valid return type!");
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Key '" + key + "' does not exist!");
    }
};
return Application;
}());
var app = new Application();
app.getValue("test"); // Should return 1234
app.getValue("test"); // Should return '1234'
```

There is no `T` in compiled JS. It will be only visible in your TypeScript, pre compiled.

Apart from that, you are not able to call:

```
getValue<VALUE>(...)
```