# Determine type of class type parameter Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

I am in a situation where I would like to determine the type of the generic type provided to a generic class. For instance assuming I have a union type, I would like to take different actions in the constructor based on the type used:

```
type MyType = string | number;
class Foo<T extends MyType>{
     private _something;
     constructor(_bar?: SomeFunc<T>){
          if(...)?
     }
}
```

From the [advanced type section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) I know I can determine the type of parameters to functions but I cannot seem to find a way to perform a check on the type of the generic provided to the actual class. Attempting to reference T in any way results in "cannot find name 'T' error (#TS2304). I found several posts [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301581/detecting-generic-type-in-typescript) but they all seem to deal with function parameters to which the first link I provided answers.

If this is not possible, as it is increasingly seeming that way, is there another pattern I can employ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to determine the type of the generic type provided to a generic class

Generics are *erased* at runtime. So you cannot use `T` in a runtime check.

Comment: Thank you and I understand that, I am looking for more of a compile time operation that I could use to select a follow on method to use.

Comment: @AndrewHunter you need to provide more of a *what do you want* but the general idea is you also give an instance of `T` e.g. `constructor(_bar?: SomeFunc<T>, someInstance:T){` and then you can do the check on `someInstance`

Comment: thankyou for the response, I was hoping to try to get away from providing an instance but it appears that is not possible in Typescript. I will be using that pattern, thanks again.